# React Proptypes being evaluated before data is returned in props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a proptype of `invoiceList: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)`. However, this prop is initially a string on page load because the API call isn't complete yet. So while an array will eventually be returned, initially a blank string is returned and I get this console warning:

`Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'invoiceList' of type 'string' supplied to 'TableBody', expected an array. Check the render method of 'PaymentTable'.`

Can I postpone the propType check or tell it it's going to be a string at first and then an array? Not sure how to handle this.

Comment: *"Not sure how to handle this."* Pass an empty array instead of a string?

Comment: @FelixKling duhhh! Thank you!